# Thymeleaf BindingResult not validating inputs?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, thymeleaf

I've been stuck on this issue for several hours now, Spring Boot Controller methods are:
**@GetMapping**

```
@GetMapping("/register")
    public String showRegistrationForm(Model model, @RequestParam(required = false) boolean registrationError) {
        UserRegistrationForm registrationForm = new UserRegistrationForm();
        model.addAttribute("registrationForm", registrationForm);
        model.addAttribute("registerError", registrationError);

        return "registration";
    }
```

And **PostMapping**:

```
@PostMapping("/register")
    public String handleRegistration(@ModelAttribute @Valid UserRegistrationForm userRegistrationForm, BindingResult result, Model model) {

            if(result.hasErrors()){
                model.addAttribute("registrationForm", userRegistrationForm);
                return "registration";
            }

        UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO();
        userDTO.setEmail(userRegistrationForm.getEmail());
        userDTO.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userRegistrationForm.getPassword()));
        userDTO.setFirstName(userRegistrationForm.getFirstName());
        userDTO.setLastName(userRegistrationForm.getLastName());
        userDTO.setRoleName(Set.of("ROLE_USER"));
        userDTO.setUsername(userRegistrationForm.getUsername());

        User users = new User();
        users.setUsername(userDTO.getUsername());
        users.setEmail(userDTO.getEmail());
        users.setPassword(userDTO.getPassword());
        users.setFirstName(userDTO.getFirstName());
        users.setLastName(userDTO.getLastName());
        users.setRoleName(userDTO.getRoleName());
        try {
            userService.saveUser(users);
            System.out.println(repository.findByEmail(users.getEmail()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (repository.findByUsername(users.getUsername()).isPresent()
                    && repository.findByEmail(users.getEmail()).isPresent()){
                logger.warn(String.format("User already exists with the username: %s and the email: %s",
                        users.getUsername(), users.getEmail()));
                throw new UserException(String.format("User already exists with the username: %s and the email: %s",
                        users.getUsername(), users.getEmail()));
            } else if (repository.findByUsername(users.getUsername()).isPresent()) {
                logger.warn(String.format("User already exists with the username: %s", users.getUsername()));
                throw new UserException(String.format("User already exists with the username: %s", users.getUsername()));
            } else if (repository.findByEmail(users.getEmail()).isPresent()) {
                logger.warn(String.format("User already exists with the email: %s", users.getEmail()));
                throw new UserException(String.format("User already exists with the email: %s", users.getEmail()));
            }
        }
        return "redirect:/login?registrationSuccess=true";
        }
```

I am using a controller advice to handle database validation, *however*, this is not the issue I am having. The controller advice handles the errors that I throw at the **bottom** of the @PostMapping.

**Thymeleaf Template segment:**

```
     <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                                        <i class="fas fa-user fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                                        <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                                            <label class="form-label" for="firstName">Name</label>
                                            <input type="text" id="firstName" th:field="*{firstName}" class="form-control" placeholder="First name"/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('firstName')}" th:errors="*{firstName}" class="alert alert-warning"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                                        <i class="fas fa-user fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                                        <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                                            <label class="form-label" for="lastName">Last name</label>
                                            <input type="text" id="lastName" th:field="*{lastName}" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name"/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('lastName')}" th:errors="*{lastName}" class="alert alert-warning"></div>
                                    </div>
```

I was expecting the **firstName** and **lastName** fields to get flagged by the **BindingResult** however none are seemingly being sent to the Template.

Here is the **RegistrationForm** with the **Validation Constraints**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Table
public class UserRegistrationForm {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_Reg_Form_Gen",
            allocationSize = 1, sequenceName = "user_Reg_Form_Gen")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_Reg_Form_Gen")
    Long registerFormID;

    @NotNull(message = "Username is required")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 16, message = "Username must be between 3 and 16 characters")
    private String username;
    @NotNull(message = "Please enter a password")
    private String password;
    private String matchPassword;
    @NotNull(message = "First name is required")
    private String firstName;
    @NotNull(message = "Last name is required")
    private String lastName;
    @NotNull(message = "Email is required")
    private String email;
}
```

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have some mandatory value in `username` and `lastname` then the `@NotNull` will not be enough. Combine it with `@NotEmpty` so that some actual value is mandatory to be passed and you don't receive just some empty string from some empty javascript input text form, which will pass through the validation.

```
@NotEmpty(message = "First name is required")
@NotNull(message = "First name is required")
private String firstName;

@NotEmpty(message = "Last name is required")
@NotNull(message = "Last name is required")
private String lastName;
```

You could as well combine both `@NotEmpty` and `@NotNull` for those string fields with the `@NotBlank`. So the optiimzed version would be

```
@NotBlank(message = "First name is required")
private String firstName;

@NotBlank(message = "Last name is required")
private String lastName;
```